# How can i show highest and lowest numbers in two rows itself?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I wanted the highest number and the lowest number in two rows but I am getting the whole output , should i have to use dense rank or rank window function ?

```
like so
```

```
popular_eco_move=spark.sql("select a.eco,b.eco_name,count(b.eco_name) as number_of_occurance  
from chess_game as a, chess_eco_codes as b where a.eco=b.eco group by a.eco,b.eco_name order 
by 
number_of_occurance desc")
popular_eco_move.show(10)



+---+--------------------+-------------------+
|eco|            eco_name|number_of_occurance|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
|C42|      Petrov Defense|                 64|
|E15|      Queen's Indian|                 56|
|C88|           Ruy Lopez|                 46|
|D37|Queen's Gambit De...|                 44|
|B90|   Sicilian, Najdorf|                 38|
|C67|           Ruy Lopez|                 37|
|B12|   Caro-Kann Defense|                 37|
|C11|              French|                 35|
|C45|         Scotch Game|                 34|
|D27|Queen's Gambit Ac...|                 32|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

Result attributes: eco, eco_name, number_of_occurences
Final result will have only two rows

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try a with clause to store a query a re-use it like this :

```
with my_select as
(select a.eco,b.eco_name,count(b.eco_name) as occurance
from `game`.`chess_game` as a, `game`.`chess_eco_codes` as b where a.eco=b.eco
group by a.eco,b.eco_name)
select * from my_select 
where occurance = (select max(occurance) from my_select) 
or occurance = (select min(occurance) from my_select)
```

Comment: you can use a group by too but i prefer it this way

Comment: JOINs are around for 30 years now, so you should also start by using them

Comment: i just my query from his query but i wouldve use join too if it was my code from the start

Comment: thanks for the help, used row_number and got the output

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PySpark, you should learn how to write it in its Pythonic way instead of just SQL.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

(df
    .withColumn('rank_asc', F.dense_rank().over(W.orderBy(F.asc('number_of_occurance'))))
    .withColumn('rank_desc', F.dense_rank().over(W.orderBy(F.desc('number_of_occurance'))))
    .where((F.col('rank_asc') == 1) | (F.col('rank_desc') == 1))
    # .drop('rank_asc', 'rank_desc') # to drop these two temp columns 
    .show()
)

+---+--------------------+-------------------+--------+---------+
|eco|            eco_name|number_of_occurance|rank_asc|rank_desc|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+--------+---------+
|C42|      Petrov Defense|                 64|       9|        1|
|D27|Queen's Gambit Ac...|                 32|       1|        9|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+--------+---------+
```